# what does dim=-1 or -2 mean in torch.sum()?

Tags: python, pytorch

let me take a 2D matrix as example:

```
mat = torch.arange(9).view(3, -1)

tensor([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]])

torch.sum(mat, dim=-2)

tensor([ 9, 12, 15])
```

I find the result of `torch.sum(mat, dim=-2)` is equal to `torch.sum(mat, dim=0)` and `dim=-1` equal to `dim=1`. My question is how to understand the negative dimension here. What if the input matrix has 3 or more dimensions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a dimensional range of \[-1,0\] in Pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59704538/what-is-a-dimensional-range-of-1-0-in-pytorch)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The minus essentially means you go backwards through the dimensions. Let A be a n-dimensional matrix. Then dim=n-1=-1, dim=n-2=-2, ..., dim=1=-(n-1), dim=0=-n. See the [numpy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#arrays-indexing) for more information, as pytorch is heavily based on numpy.

Answer (score 31):

A tensor has multiple dimensions, ordered as in the following figure.
There is a forward and backward indexing. Forward indexing uses positive integers, backward indexing uses negative integers.

Example:

-1 will be the last one, in our case it will be dim=2

-2 will be dim=1

-3 will be dim=0

[image]

Comment: Why is there a dimension **zero**? Does this refer to collections starting from zero?

Comment: It is common to start counting starting from zero instead of 1