# What is a dimensional range of [-1,0] in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, softmax

So I'm struggling to understand some terminology about collections in Pytorch. I keep running into the same kinds of errors about the *range* of my tensors being incorrect, and when I try to Google for a solution often the explanations are further confusing.

Here is an example:

```py
m = torch.nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
input = torch.tensor([0.3300, 0.3937, -0.3113, -0.2880])
output = m(input)
```

I don't see anything wrong with the above code, and I've defined my `LogSoftmax` to accept a 1 dimensional input. So according to my experience with other programming languages the collection `[0.3300, 0.3937, -0.3113, -0.2880]` is a single dimension.

The above triggers the following error for `m(input)`:

```
IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

What does that mean?

I passed in a *one dimensional* tensor, but then it tells me that it was expecting a range of `[-1, 0], but got 1`.

- A range of what?
- Why is the error comparing a dimension of `1` to `[-1, 0]`?
- What do the two numbers `[-1, 0]` mean?

I searched for an explanation for this error, and I find things like this link which make no sense to me as a programmer:

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/5554#issuecomment-370456868

So I was able to fix the above code by adding another dimension to my tensor data.

```py
m = torch.nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
input = torch.tensor([[-0.3300, 0.3937, -0.3113, -0.2880]])
output = m(input)
```

So that works, but I don't understand how `[-1,0]` explains a nested collection.

Further experiments showed that the following also works:

```py
m = torch.nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
input = torch.tensor([[0.0, 0.1], [1.0, 0.1], [2.0, 0.1]])
output = m(input)
```

So `dim=1` means a collection of collections, but I don't understand how that means `[-1, 0]`.

When I try using `LogSoftmax(dim=2)`

```py
m = torch.nn.LogSoftmax(dim=2)
input = torch.tensor([[0.0, 0.1], [1.0, 0.1], [2.0, 0.1]])
output = m(input)
```

The above gives me the following error:

> IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-2, 1], but got 2)

Confusion again that `dim=2` equals `[-2, 1]`, because where did the `1` value come from?

I can fix the error above by **nesting** collections another level, but at this point I don't understand what values `LogSoftmax` is expecting.

```py
m = torch.nn.LogSoftmax(dim=2)
input = torch.tensor([[[0.0, 0.1]], [[1.0, 0.1]], [[2.0, 0.1]]])
output = m(input)
```

I am super confused by this terminology `[-1, 0]` and `[-2, 1]`?

If the first value is the nested depth, then why is it **negative** and what could the second number mean?

There is no **error code** associated with this error. So it's been difficult to find documentation on the subject. It appears to be an *extremely* common error people get confused by and nothing that I can find in the Pytorch documentation that talks specifically about it.

Comment: Another question was just asked an hour ago about the same thing. It adds some light to the subject, but I would like an answer that helps me understand this better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59702785/what-does-dim-1-or-2-mean-in-torch-sum

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When specifying a tensor's dimension as an argument for a function (e.g. `m = torch.nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)`) you can either use *positive* dimension indexing starting with 0 for the first dimension, 1 for the second etc.
Alternatively, you can use *negative* dimension indexing to start from the last dimension to the first: -1 indicate the last dimension, -2 the second from last etc.

*Example:*
If you have a 4D tensor of dimensions `b`-by-`c`-by-`h`-by-`w` then

- The "batch" dimension (the first) can be accessed as either `dim=0` or `dim=-4`.
- The "channel" dimension (the second) can be accessed as either `dim=1` or `dim=-3`.
- The "height"/"vertical" dimension (the third) can be accessed as either `dim=2` or `dim=-2`.
- The "width"/"horizontal" dimension (the fourth) can be accessed as either `dim=3` or `dim=-1`.

Therefore, if you have a 4D tensor `dim` argument can take values in the range `[-4, 3]`.

In your case you have a 1D tensor and therefore `dim` argument can be wither 0 or -1 (which in this deprecate case amounts to the same dimension).

Comment: Thanks this makes more sense now. Why is the error `[-2, 1]` for `dim=2` if that means 3 dimensions, then shouldn't the error be something like `[-2, 1, 0]`?

Comment: @Reactgular it's a range between -2 and 1. Zero is in the range